# How to extact Number from string?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I want to extract 2,5 from "2,5 km" string in typescript. i tried parseFloat(distance.replace (  /[^0-9,]/g, '' ) but it returns just 2

Comment: no i need to delete km from the string

Comment: You already have code that does that `distance.replace( /[^0-9,]/g, '' )`

Comment: it returns only 2

Comment: No, adding `parseFloat` does that. That statement alone returns `"2,5"`, assuming `distance` is `"2,5 km"`. Run the following in the browser's console: `var distance = "2,5 km"; distance.replace( /[^0-9,]/g, '' )`

Comment: Before calling parseFloat() I would call "2,5 km".substring(3) then use "2,5".replace(',', '.') to replace comma with a dot. Then parseFloat on "2.5" should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove last 3 characters : " km" and then replace comma with dot like this :

```
String distanceOriginal = "2,5 km";
String distanceParsable = distanceOriginal.substring(0, distanceOriginal.length() - 3);
distanceParsable = distanceParsable.replace(',', '.');
Float distanceParsed = Float.parseFloat(distanceParsable);
```

I just tryed in debug :

```
Float.parseFloat("2,5 km".substring(0, "2,5 km".length()-3).replace(',','.'));
```

It returns 2.5